# word frequency count strange results

Tags: python, word-frequency

When doing a word frequency count on my corpus, the results seem inacurate (are not the most frequent words to my feeling, and the frequency count is only one or two) and some results show 'as over\xe2' and '\xad'. Can anyone help?

```
def toptenwords(mycorpus):
  mywords = mycorpus.words()
  nocapitals = [word.lower() for word in mywords] 
  filtered = [word for word in nocapitals if word not in stoplist]
  nopunctuation= [s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in filtered] 
  woordcounter = {}
     for word in nopunctuation:
        if word in wordcounter:
          woordcounter[word] += 1
        else:
          woordcounter[word] = 1
    frequentwords = sorted(wordcounter.iteritems(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
    top10 = frequentwords[:10]
    woord1 = frequentwords[1]
    woord2 = frequentwords[2]
    woord3 = frequentwords[3]
    woord4 = frequentwords[4]
    woord5 = frequentwords[5]
    woord6 = frequentwords[6]
    woord7 = frequentwords[7]
    woord8 = frequentwords[8]
    woord9 = frequentwords[9]
    woord10 = frequentwords[10]
    print "De 10 meest frequente woorden zijn: ", woord1, ",", woord2, ",", woord3, ",",    woord4, ",", woord5, ",", woord6, ",", woord7, ",", woord8, ",", woord9, "en", woord10
```

Code is originally in dutch, this is the NOT translated code:

```
def toptienwoorden(mycorpus):
   woorden = mycorpus.words()
   zonderhoofdletters = [word.lower() for word in woorden] 
   gefiltered = [word for word in zonderhoofdletters if word not in stoplijst] 
   geenleestekens = [s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in gefiltered] 
   woordteller = {}
   for word in geenleestekens:
      if word in woordteller:
         woordteller[word] += 1
      else:
         woordteller[word] = 1
  frequentewoorden = sorted(woordteller.iteritems(), key = itemgetter(1), reverse = True)
  top10 = frequentewoorden[:10]
  woord1 = frequentewoorden[1]
  woord2 = frequentewoorden[2]
  woord3 = frequentewoorden[3]
  woord4 = frequentewoorden[4]
  woord5 = frequentewoorden[5]
  woord6 = frequentewoorden[6]
  woord7 = frequentewoorden[7]
  woord8 = frequentewoorden[8]
  woord9 = frequentewoorden[9]
  woord10 = frequentewoorden[10]
  print "De 10 meest frequente woorden zijn: ", woord1, ",", woord2, ",", woord3, ",",    woord4, ",", woord5, ",", woord6, ",", woord7, ",", woord8, ",", woord9, "en", woord10
```

Comment: you have to show us some code.

Comment: show us code *and* data :P

Comment: and the wierd letters are unicode chars, `'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX'` and `'SOFT HYPHEN'` :P

Comment: I translated it from dutch so you would know what the arguments mean. I will post it in dutch now

Comment: Can you give a download link for your corpus?

Comment: Well, the most obvious problem is that the most frequent word will be `frequentewoorden[0]`, which you silently ignore.

Comment: @wooble I'm sorry I don't understand. I am an absolute beginner in Python.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel I'm sorry I don't have an online version.

Comment: @JohnDoe: in nearly every programming language, arrays (and in Python's case, lists) are 0-indexed; the first element is element 0.

Comment: Okay I got it! Great thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, you make a sub-list of the top ten, but then don't actually do anything with it, since you get each individual word from the original list again.

Comment: Yes I see! I adjusted my script and it now does what it's supposed to. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). It is perfect for counting the frequency of (hashable) items and it has a `most_common` method which can return the top ten most frequent items without you having to code the logic yourself:

```
import string
import collections


def topNwords(mywords, N = 10, stoplist = set(), filtered = set()):
    # mywords = mycorpus.words()
    nocapitals = [word.lower() for word in mywords]
    filtered = [word for word in nocapitals if word not in stoplist]
    nopunctuation = [s.translate(None, string.punctuation) for s in filtered]
    woordcounter = collections.Counter(nopunctuation)
    top_ten = [word for word, freq in woordcounter.most_common(N)]
    return top_ten


top_ten = topNwords('This is a test. It is only a test. In case of a real emergency'.split(), N = 10)
print("De 10 meest frequente woorden zijn: {w}".format(w = ', '.join(top_ten)))
```

Comment: While this is the best way to do it, I can't help but feel you just gave a complete answer to a homework question...

Comment: Not really, because I don't have the most recent python version because I am using NLTK. So the "counter" function doesn't work on this version of Python. However the anwser might still be a good one for other members.

Comment: @JohnDoe: If you are using `NLTK`, check out [FreqDist](http://nltk.org/book/ch01.html#frequency_distribution_index_term).